# Crash when using Replace with Access and ASP

Tags: asp-classic, ms-access-2007

I'm quite frustraded, I feel as if I'm making a very basic mistake. I've checked and re-checked the code several times, googled for this crash, but couldn't find anything.

I'm currently trying to create a **detail extract page in ASP from an Access db** but my screen **crashes** whenever my extract **query contains** a **Replace** function.

Side note: **the query works perfectly in Access** - the crash happens only when I try to run it in the ASP code

[The dabase can be downloaded in this link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1P1M0F7LJpjWuINaRBc_g7MXCPoo3_rsV)

This is the code:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM myQueryReplace"
Set objAdoCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objAdoCon.Open strDatabaseConnectionExtract
Set objRec = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objRec.Open strSQL, objAdoCon
'Check If the RecordSet object returned any records'
If (NOT (objRec.EOF)) AND (NOT (objRec.BOF)) Then
    %><table><%
    For Each subVarColumn in objRec.Fields%>
        <th align='center' bgcolor='#b0c4de'  height='50'><%=subVarColumn.name%></th><%
    Next
    Do Until objRec.EOF%>
            <tr class="highlightTableBody"><%
            For Each subVarColumn in objRec.Fields%>
                <td style="text-align: center;"><%=subVarColumn.value%></td><%
            Next%>
            </tr><%
        objRec.MoveNext
    Loop
    %></table><%
End If
Set objRec = Nothing
Set objAdoCon = Nothing
```

All I want is to  be able to print the query that has "replace"s

Comment: If the problem is in the SQL it might help if you show your query

Comment: @John I apologize, I've just added the SQL in the ASP side on the original post; it "SELECT * FROM myQueryReplace"

The SQL in the database is this one:
    SELECT 
          myTable.myTextField
        , IIf(myTable.myTextField Is Null,'',myTable.myTextField) AS textWithIsnull
        , Len(textWithIsnull) AS textWithIsnull_length, IIf(textWithIsnull_length=0,True,False) AS doNotReplace
        , IIf(textWithIsnull_length=0,'',Replace(textWithIsnull,'o','0')) AS textWithReplace
        , myTable.ID
    FROM myTable;

Answer (score -1):

I Just checked the way you said. and downloaded database and set asp page and code which you gave and its working perfectly the way you wanted

see below screen shot.. 
http://prntscr.com/h8boyj

connection string i have used this ..

Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=[database path];Persist Security Info=False;

Comment: Interesting. Do you think it could be something in my IIS settings?
@Vijaysinh Jadeja

Comment: did you use the same connection string?    which i gave?  it may be provider which you use does not support..   I dont think so that there is IIS setting.. for this.. as far as you used the same connection string and its work with normal query then it must be work with query too..

Comment: Yessir, I tried it with your connection string and it still didn't work

Comment: humm.. can you try with some different PC